# Probability of $n$ successes in the first $k$ trials given that there were $n+1$ successes in the total of trials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm having trouble with the following problem:

A man found that $3$ out of $10$ inspected bottles were defective. What is the probability that the $2$ first defective bottles were found in the first $7$ inspected bottles? The probability that a bottle is defective is $0.1988$.

Let $A$ be the event that the $2$ first defective bottles were found in the first $7$ inspected bottles and $B$ the event that $3$ out of $10$ inspected bottles were defective. I need to find $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A∩B)}{P(B)}$. Using binomial distribution,$P(B)=C^{10}_3\times0.1988^3\times0.8012^7=0.20$

I'm stuck finding $P(A∩B)$. How can I proceed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by a combinatoric argument.

YOu know you have 3 wrong bottle in 10 bottle. The number of order to get the three bottle is $${10\choose 3}$$

The number of oder where you get two bottle in the first 7 and one bottle in the last 3 is 
$${7\choose 2}{3\choose 1}$$

So the probability you need is

$$\frac{{7\choose 2}{3\choose 1}}{10\choose 3} $$

Answer (score 1):

We need 2 defects in the first 7 and 1 defect in the last 3:
$$
(C^7_2\cdot 0.1988^2\cdot 0.8012^5)\cdot(C^3_1\cdot 0.1988^1\cdot 0.8012^2)=C^7_2\cdot C^3_1\cdot 0.1988^3\cdot 0.8012^7.
$$